# Send CSV files as single email attachment

Tags: python, email, csv, email-attachments

Have a script test.py which will generate 2 to 3 csv files making sql queries.
CSV files will be generated and saved in the same path as  test.py.
Generation of csv file is proper but the email attachment is not working
Below is my code snippet :

```
import smtplib
import csv
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.message import Message
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

with open('record1.csv', 'wb') as f:
    fieldnames = ['Name','No audits']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for data in query:
        writer.writerow({'Name' : data[0], 'No audits': data[1]})

## below code as problem 
#Mail format
COMMASPACE = ', '
SERVER = "localhost"

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['Subject'] = 'Audit records'
emailfrom = "xyz" // Giving proper outlook mail id 
emailto = ['abc'] // // Giving proper outlook mail id lists

msg['From'] = emailfrom
msg['To'] = COMMASPACE.join(emailto)
msg.preamble = 'List of  audit records '
csvfiles = ['record1.csv', 'record2.csv']

for csv in csvfiles:
        print csv
        with open(csv) as fp:
                record = MIMEText(fp.read())
        msg.attach(record)

print "INFO: "
server = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER)
server.sendmail(emailfrom, emailto, msg.as_string())
server.quit()
```

script runs without errors but no email is sent

Comment: Does the email get sent if you comment out the attachment part?

Comment: No , if i comment out the csv files part and try sending even then its not sent

Comment: Well then you should continue to reduce your test program to the smallest program which still shows a problem.  This prevents us from wasting time on red herrings such as "attachment" as mentioned in your title.

Comment: What is the `query` in your sample of code ???

Comment: that is a mongodb query im making which is something  like 
       for data in db.audit_records.find(): 

this is working fine and i'm able to generate csv files with records. But not able to send those csv files as email attachemnt

Comment: WHat is `smtp` servier you use ???

Comment: Version of Netmon ????

Comment: im not sure about the version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the login part. And you should provide proper server  and port in smtplib.SMTP().

Change last 3 line with following. Following code is for gmail, update code as per outlook.

```
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(emailfrom, 'password')
server.sendmail(emailfrom, emailto, msg.as_string())
server.quit()
```

**Edit:**

import following:

```
from email import encoders
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
import os
```

And replace loop with following code.

```
for csv in csvfiles:
        print csv
        with open(csv) as fp:
            record = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
            record.set_payload(fp.read())
            encoders.encode_base64(record)
            record.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment',
                              filename=os.path.basename(csv))
        msg.attach(record)
```

Comment: Login is not required to send to you office outlook mail servers.

Comment: Im able to send mail using below link
http://effbot.org/pyfaq/how-do-i-send-mail-from-a-python-script.htm 

But not attachment :(

Comment: @kittudeopa then how mail is sent without login? Didn't get your last comment.

Comment: Im using my office SMTP server and also to and from is office mail_id's . So login is not required. And it works.

Comment: You are able to send mail using  effbot.org/pyfaq/how-do-i-send-mail-from-a-python-script.htm .. without specifying port and server as 'localhost' ?

Comment: No. Im specifying  ip and port . sorry for the confusion !!

Comment: @kittudeopa MIMETEXT() is used for email body. check edited answer and try.

Comment: I am in the same boat, I need to send email from linux server with csv attached, from the same path, where the script is running. It should reach to outlook receivers. What kind of details I need ?